# getting the value of a checkbox in play framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, playframework

I am using twitter bootstrap with play framework. 
I would like to use a simple if construct, and if the checkbox is checked I would like to use a different link, than when the checkbox is unchecked. But I don't know how to get the value of the checkbox.

```
<div class="span11 no_margin_left">
    <hr>
    <label class="span5 checkbox" id="checkBoxDetails2"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxDetails" id="checkBoxDetails">Use these Details as Delivery Details                                            </label>
    #{if checkBoxDetails}<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="#collapse4">Continue</a><br>
    #{/if}#{else}<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="#collapse3">Continue</a><br>#{/else}
    <br> <br>
</div>
```

Comment: If my answer has helped I'd love it if you would accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand of your question, in simple Javascript:

```
if(checkBoxDetails.checked){...}
```

or even

```
if(checkBoxDetails.checked == true){...}
```